# What does "There's a route but no loop" mean?

Tags: genshiken

"There's a route but no loop" is the episode title for Genshiken Nidaime - 08.

I'm assuming this is a reference to gal games, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a double pun on the pronunciation and game mechanics, "ruuto" (ルート) and "ruupu" (ループ) sounds similar.

In VN/galges, you have to do a playthrough (loop) to unlock certain routes.